# How do I define IDataObject for VirtualTreeview drag and drop?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, virtualtreeview

I'm working in Delphi 10 Seattle and I have Virtual Treeview version 7.2.1 installed.  It's been some years since I needed to drag and drop in a treeview.
I created handlers for OnDragOver and OnDragDrop.  DragType is dtOLE.  DragMode is dmAutomatic.
The problem is that the compiler gives me an error "E2005: IDataObject is not a type identifier."
And it isn't defined in VirtualTrees.pas.
What do I do to define IDataObject?

Comment: I'm just sorting items in a grid-style list, within the treeview.  Just moving nodes up and down.

Comment: `IDataObject` is defined by Windows. Check Delphi's Winapi-related units, like `ActiveX` or `Shellapi`, it is likely defined in one of them (i dont have a system onhand to look myself at the moment).

Comment: IDataObject is an interface defined in WinAPI.ActiveX.

Comment: Ken, That's it.  Thank you and Remy!